# Characteristic roots of AR polynomial

Tags: regression, time-series

I understand why we need to find the unit root, but i get stuck when i try to actually find it. This is probably an easy exercise (im new to the topic), so i hope you guys can help me. I know this is stationary (using matlab), but i would like to be able to see it, when it is written out, so i can search for it my self. So really, i just need a solution for, with all of the steps:

$$y_{t}=\delta+0.4 y_{t-1}+0.3 y_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t}$$

I get stuck with the constant.

Comment: is the answer clear @mbih?

Answer (score 0):

Roots of the characteristic polynomial (i.e. denoted commonly as $\phi(B)$) are found using the recursive portion of AR equation, which doesn't include the constant part:
$$\phi(B)y_t=c+\epsilon_t$$
where $\phi(B)=1-0.4B-0.3B^2$